# Disable font ligatures in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to disable font ligatures in jetpack compose? I haven't found any official doc about such possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the way.

```
h1 = TextStyle(
            color = color,
            fontFamily = fonts,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
            fontFeatureSettings = "liga 0"
        )
```